# Is there any way to measure of Gaussian-ness?

Tags: noise, gaussian

I have some sampled data that has $1/f$ noise in it, with departures from the mean. These are long term departures. I could use something like a median filter but the window length would be longer than I would like.

- Is there any way to measure its departure from a Gaussian distribution?
- Or measure how 'Gaussian-like' a time series statstical sample is?

Comment: The Gaussian distribution has some properties that are useful. You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Properties).

Comment: I have troubles understanding was you really are looking for: a measure of gaussianity? Characterization of $1/f$ noise? Why is your original data Gaussian? Why does a median filter come into play?

Comment: I have taken a few statistical courses and I'm aware of the math. I want to know what other people use

Answer (score 3):

One way to measure the similarity between two distributions is the [Kullbeck-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). Granted, it is not a norm because it is not symmetric, but it is a way of quantifying the distance between two pdfs.

EDIT: There is a topic called "[Normality testing" or "Gaussianity testing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test) that is devoted to that very task. Perhaps some tools from that field will help.

Answer (score 3):

A classical measure of "gaussianity" is the kurtosis of your random variable (RV). Kurtosis is the forth order cumulant of a RV. Say $y$ is your RV with zero mean, the kurtosis can be defined as: $$kurt(y)=E[y^4] - 3(E[y^2])^2$$ If $y$ is gaussian, $E[y^4]=3(E[y^2])^2$ and therefore $$kurt(y)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3504369

In this reference the authors check for gaussian behavior of the 1/f noise of a resistor using a fourth order frequency spectrum.